# Is sound of USS Enterprise’s automatic door opening indeed toilet flushing sound?

Tags: star-trek

According to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shittymoviedetails/comments/pqwakv/in_star_trek_2009_the_sound_of_the_automatic/),

> In Star Trek (2009), the sound of the automatic doors opening on the U.S.S. Enterprise is a Russian train's toilet flushing. (No, really)

How much truth is there in it? Is there any official source?

Comment: Note that it would appear to be a *vacuum* toilet flush, not the typical household water toilet flush.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The sound designer, [Ann Schibelli](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0778439/), is quoted on [trektoday](https://www.trektoday.com/content/2009/12/star-trek-xi-making-sounds-in-outer-space/) as saying:

> "The design for the Enterprise door is such a signature sound that
> we’ve heard throughout the original series,” she said. "I wanted to
> make it sound, you know, that classic [sound]. I was working on
> another project and we had recorded some Russian toilet flushes on a
> train. And it was one of those air flushes that had just a really cool
> vacuum suction sound. And as soon as I heard it, I said, ‘this is the
> sound for the Enterprise door.’ So that’s really what it is, a toilet
> flush."

Comment: Unlike the spoofed door in the William Shatner scenes in *Airplane 2*, which just sounds like a person saying "Ssshhhk", and indeed, a person saying "Ssshhhk" is also the command to open and close the door...

Comment: Toilets on a Russian train, eh? Clearly, it wasn't just the characters on the show that wanted to boldly go where no one had gone before.

Comment: This really just prompts the question: why in the first place were they recording Russian toilet flushes on trains?

Comment: Presumably that other project mentioned has some scenes on a train in Russia? Doesn't seem that mysterious.